# Swift remove data stored in UITableViewController from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom class that extends UIViewController and contains a table view, with an array that stores data that populates the table view. For my custom cells, I have a button that when pressed, should remove that cell from the table view. However, I haven't been able to find a way to remove the data from the array in the table view controller and reload the data from the cell's class. Some of the answers I've seen on similar posts suggest notifications or delegation, but due to the structure of my app (tab controller) and that I already use notifications for another feature, the former is inefficient, and I don't know how to use the latter in this situation.
This is the code for the custom cell class:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var removeButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func remove(sender: AnyObject) {
        // don't know what to put here
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
         super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

And here is the table view controller class:

```
class CustomController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

    var data: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.dataSource = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: CustomCell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        // put content in
        return cell
    }
}
```

The array `data` is what I want to access from `remove` in `CustomCell`. The closest I've gotten is using `self.superview.superview.superview` in `CustomCell`, which returns the view that `CustomController` controls. However, I have no way to get an instance of `CustomController` without instantiating a new one. How do I modify a variable in `CustomController` from the `CustomCell` class?

Comment: To modify your data array you also don't ne AN instance of CustomController, you ned THE instance of CustomController, holding your data array property below in my answer you find a way to get a reference to THE instance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Custom Cell add this

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
 var customControllerReference: CustomController?
}
```

And in your Custom Controller in cellForRowAtIndexPath add this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: CustomCell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.customControllerReference = self
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Now you have a reference the the instance of CustomController, which is holding your TableView, that holds the instance of the UITableViewCell and you can call any func in your controller, or change a property of it by just calling customControllerReference.doStuff()